# Liquid oxygen how do they use it as fuel?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, aerodynamics, rocket-science

Rockets are said to be using liquid oxygen as fuel. How do they use liquid oxygen since it's just oxygen, it only helps in the combustion process. How can it be a fuel on its own?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a fuel (by any reasonable definition) it's used as an oxidizer along with a fuel - typically kerosene or liquid hydrogen